# Why does my grease pencil's filled outline turn black in render preview?

Tags: animation, grease-pencil

I used two different colors for the fill outline and the fill color. You can see the difference in color with solid mode on, but when I turn on the render preview, the outlines turn black. I have the color management on standard, and I tried adjusting the alpha but it seems like the lines literally turned black. Does anyone know what's going on? [image: solid mode vs. render preview]
The picture below is what my materials look like.

[image: materials list]

Comment: Can you please add a screenshot of the materials you are using for this?

Answer (score 1):

okay so I figured out that I needed to change the vertex color to the color of the outline. I just needed to open the materials tab and drag and drop the outline color to the vertex color, then things actually started to look right. Also, another way to do this,(and easier) is to turn on paint mode to material. This will use your material base color to paint instead. [image: paint mode selected]
oh, and one more note to add here, the drawing doesn't change, you have to draw with it to see the difference. It was a little confusing and frustrating because I have to redraw my frames now with this new setting, but I'm glad there's a way to fix this.